# cypress session redirects to blank page

Tags: reactjs, testing, cypress

I am new to cypress and perhaps missing some key understanding in how sessions work within cypress.

I am building a simple test that will do a login in to the system and then perform a certain action
Bellow is my test. The login function performs as expected, but when the first `it` finishes the sequence goes to a blank page and unless I do another login in the next `it` it doesn't work.
How can I persist the session between different `it`s and not have it jump pages?

```
describe('create cycle', () =>{

    it("login as super user", () =>{
    cy.session('login', ()=>{
            cy.visit('/')
            login();
        })  
    })

    it('start cycle', ()=>{  
      cy.get("#cycles-library > ul > #library-item-2").click();
      cy.get("#create-cycle").click()
      cy.get("#startDate > label").first().click()
      cy.get("#duration > label").first().click()
      cy.get('#groups-input').click()
      cy.get("body>div").last().contains('group 2').click()
      cy.get("button#create-cycle").click()

    })

})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cy.session()` generally works with `beforeEach()` to ensure proper session data is set for each test.

The pattern is

```js
describe('tests requiring session data', () =>{

  beforeEach(() =>{
    cy.session('login', ()=>{
      cy.visit('/')
      login();
    })  
  })

  it('test that expects logged-in status', () => {  

  it('another one', () => {  
})
```

It may appear that you are performing the login each time, but it's not so. The `cy.session()` is a caching function, it runs once on the first test then just restores the session data for each subsequent test.

You can think of it like React hooks `useEffect()` with an empty dependency list, which also runs just once in the component lifecycle.

Since you ***also*** have a test for logging in, you should perform that separately in another `describe()` block, since the initial conditions are different for each test.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had to set the testIsolation property to false. After that cy.session started to work and not ending with a blank page:

```
describe('my tests',{ testIsolation: false }, () => {...});
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm using Cypress, Auth0 React SDK. Next.js with Auth0 React SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Every `it` will clear the navigator storage, including your session.

To handle this you should create a [cypress command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands) which will create the session for you, this command can change depending on your athentication.

For example, if you have a simple POST `/login` endpoint, which receives an username and password params and return session data has to be stored in cookies, you can make something like:

```js
// cypress/support/commands.js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
  cy.request('POST', `${Cypress.env('apiUrl')}/users/login`, {
    username: Cypress.env('userEmail'),
    password: Cypress.env('userPassword'),
  }).then((response) => {
    cy.setCookie('sessionId', response.body.sessionId)
    cy.setCookie('userId', response.body.userId)
    cy.setCookie('userName', response.body.userName)
  })
})
```

And in you test or `beforeEach` test:

```js
...
    it('start cycle', () => {  
      cy.login()
      // cy.get("#cycles-library > ul > #library-item-2").click();
      // cy.get("#create-cycle").click()
      // cy.get("#startDate > label").first().click()
      // cy.get("#duration > label").first().click()
      // cy.get('#groups-input').click()
      // cy.get("body>div").last().contains('group 2').click()
      // cy.get("button#create-cycle").click()
    })
...
```

I recommend you to [stub](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept) [each specific request](https://www.jayfreestone.com/writing/stubbing-graphql-cypress)
, having a list of all request/response from your app, and then use it to test your backend. This make things faster, and easier.

Pact use this [strategy](https://pactflow.io/how-pact-works/?utm_source=ossdocs&utm_campaign=getting_started#slide-1), but you don't need to use Pact necessarily, just keep your test data synced to test back-end and front-end, or things can blow in production even if your CI is passing, a monorepo can help with that.

Comment: so I do need to perform login after each it, right?
A follow up questions, please:
A single test, no matter how long it be, should be in a single 'it' function or broken down to logical blocks within different 'its'?

Comment: It should be in a single `it` but it doesn't have to be long, if you separate the 'GIVEN' state of your test and the 'THEN' assertions in fixture files your test should be small enough.

Comment: One important concept, is that your app should be testable. Doesn't metter how good you are with any testing tool, if your software is not design to be tested you will fail. With cypress is important to be able to set your app state before you do the actions and assertions.

Answer (score 0):

It is not funny at all.

Well first of all I did common mistake, not doing assertion. Then I fixed it. Ok, everything worked fine yesterday.

Today, I have a same problem, without making uncommon changes.

So after spending 1 hour, I just replaced positions between cy.login and cy.visit in test case. And it worked.

Before it was [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZvzc.png)

After I made [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URaRa.png)

It worked correct.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577)